# Query a Azure Database for MySQL DB from a python notebook

Tags: mysql, azure

I was trying to insert the data from a CSV file to a Azure Database for MySQL DB and i'm stuck in the process of establishing a connexion.

I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/connect-python

I did everything but still got stuck with this error:

2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<serv_name>.mysql.database.azure.com:' (10060)

Here is my code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd
import time
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

config = {
  'host':'<serv_name>.mysql.database.azure.com',
  'user':'<username>',
  'password':'<password>',
  'database':'<db_name>',
  'port': port,
  'ssl_disabled': False,
  'client_flags': [mysql.connector.ClientFlag.SSL],
  'ssl_ca': 'DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem'
}

# Construct connection string

try:
   conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   print("Connection established")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with the user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cursor = conn.cursor()
```

[image: Here is my directory]

Don't take into account data_local.csv it's just the data that's in my blob storage that i pulled

If you have any recommendation i'll be very thankful

Comment: ok so basically i just needed to add an ip rule to accept connection from my local vscode haha, if someone is stuck just go here Home>Server Azure DataBase for MySQL> your serv > networking >Add 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 and test with this method: 

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password="passwd", 
                              host="your-serv.mysql.database.azure.com", 
                              port=3306, database="your_db", 
                              ssl_ca="DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem", 
                              ssl_disabled=False)

Comment: Post this as an answer, if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone is interested here is the final code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd
import time
import csv
import mysql.connector
    
STORAGEACCOUNTURL= "https://-----.blob.core.windows.net/"
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= "---"
CONTAINERNAME= "-----"
BLOBNAME= "---/data.csv"

# get csv from blob
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME, snapshot=None)
blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()

# Get blob data as bytes
blob_data_bytes = blob_data.content_as_bytes()

# Decode bytes to string using UTF-8 encoding
blob_data_str = blob_data_bytes.decode('utf-8')

# Parse CSV data
csv_data = csv.reader(blob_data_str.splitlines())

# Iterate over rows
for row in csv_data:
    print(row)

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password="passwd", host="your-serv.mysql.database.azure.com", port=3306, database="your_db", ssl_ca="DigiCertGlobalRootG2.crt.pem", ssl_disabled=False) 

cursor = cnx.cursor()

next(csv_data)
for row in csv_data:

    query = "INSERT INTO planets (name, distance, stellar_magnitude, planet_type) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    data = (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])

    cursor.execute(query, data)

cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```